# Wordpress Sitemap including pages that aren't there

Tags: plugins, seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

I dont know if this is a severe cache, or a bug of sorts, I've installed multiple "seo" plugins to try and fix this, trawled the file system, cleaned the database, I don't know what is generating this sitemap and why it includes links to things that aren't there!

https://eastcoasttyreandauto.com.au/sitemap.xml

Example: https://eastcoasttyreandauto.com.au/articles/662043552335510/3138icps06200/ezdrdmh/114838124

Is there any tricks to figure out what is controlling this sitemap?

Comment: did you tried generating sitemap manually?